# Hadoop installation status

Tags: hadoop, configuration, installation, debian

I'm running debian. I'm new to Hadoop. Sometime back, I was trying to install Hadoop. I'm not sure if I've successfully installed. When I enter command at terminal

```
 hadoop version
```

I see the output:

```
 Hadoop 2.7.1
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 15ecc87ccf4a0228f35af08fc56de536e6ce657a
Compiled by jenkins on 2015-06-29T06:04Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum fc0a1a23fc1868e4d5ee7fa2b28a58a
This command was run using /home/xxxxxxx/java/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar
```

Is hadoop installed properly? If not, what other tests I've to do? If yes, is there some simple "get-started" tutorial/exercise you're aware of, that can help me get started with?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes your installation is correct. Do googling you will find lots of hadoop tutorials

Comment: Whoa, Thanks! Will do it!